# How to list my app downloads

Tags: android, sd-card

I'm working on books library in my android app... so I want to add a functionality that allows the user to view the books that he/she has downloaded by my app..

any idea or hint to work this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution depends a bit on the details you want to store for the books. If you only want to store the book title and author and you don't want to deal with a database yet then SharedPreferences might be an option. But they are more like Java Properties files and with this said not a good solution for persisting more complex data structures.

If you want to store more metadata of the books (e.g. the current read position, bookmarks, etc.) then you will need a database sooner or later. I recommend thinking about the data model first and then start with the SQLite database included in Android.

You can find more details here [Android Developers - Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to keep track is whenever a book is downloaded store the required data in database and retrive it whenever required or delete it from database if no required in future.

Try this way.

Answer (score 1):

If your app has already downloaded books, then you need a `ListView` to display them.
If, however, the problem is both in saving and listing, you should read the dev guide, esp about using `File` and `getExternalFileDir`.